Word becomes unsaved state when the addin button is clicked
When user clicked ribbon addin button, word document becomes unsaved state.
It is the unexpected behavior for customers because they do not change document anything.
Are there anyway to suppress this behavior?
Repro steps:

setup the word taskpane addin following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator
just in case, make taskpane.html almost empty = <html><body>Hello!</body></html>, in order to ensure AddIn do not anything.
Launch word, load any document, set auto-save off
Side load the addin
Ctrl+S on word document pane, confirm the document becomes "saved" state.
Click Addin ribbon button
Result: document becomes unsaved state,  EVERY TIME the Addin ribbon button is clicked.

Expect: document should keep saved state unless document content is changed.
NOTE: even if I added <runtimes><runtime lifetime="long" /></runtimes> into manifest, the ribbon addin icon click clears saved state. In this case, what the ribbon button does is just to activate the addin side pane.
